# Escaping the @ symbol when using CSL in pandoc

Tags: markdown, pandoc

How does one write @mytwitterhandle when using pandoc with csl citation formatting enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\@mytwitterhandle` or `` `@mytwitterhandle` ``